# Sitecore not registering goal

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I am running Sitecore 6.5 rev. 120706 with DMS 2.0.1 rev. 120706. Sitecore is not registering goals reached for visitors. The log is showing

> ERROR Exception during registration: System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column 'LastAccessedDateTime' in table 'AutomationStates' is DBNull.

Checking the LastAccessedDateTime column in SQL Server rows aren't being populated:

[image]

Is there any known workarounds or a way to populate this data via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into our installation `[AutomationStates].[LastAccessedDateTime]` is marked as allowing `Nulls`. You could try to download a clean Analytics database, generate creation scripts for both and run a diff tool to see where your database is corrupted.

The update script for DMS201 does not contain any references to `LastAccessedDateTime`, so it must come from a prior update.

Comment: Thanks Jan as you said installing a clean analytics DB fixed the issue   cheers